# MX Notify sends emails to some members, but not all

Tags: notification, mx-notify

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this problem, but it seems that MX Notify is sending emails to some of my members, but not others.

I have several triggers set up to send emails to the authors of SAEF entries whenever an admin changes their statuses. (Members can submit recipes as entries, and admins can reject them by switching the status to Closed or Request-Resubmision or whatever).

Apparently some members are not getting emails. I've checked the database, and they all have "Accept email from administrators" checked in their profiles.

Any tips on how to solve this?